# Current state of Canvas in IE(2012), what are the recommended alternatives?

Tags: internet-explorer, canvas, three.js

This thread is 6 months old
[canvas animation to work in IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7469589/canvas-animation-to-work-in-ie)

Was hoping there might be an update or recommended best practice in making sure canvas animations are viewable in most browsers including IE, since IE7-8 account for approx 25% of users in North America currently.

From my limited research it would seem that three.js is the best choice since you can export to SVG for IE support but please correct me if I am mistaken.